# What email services or applictions allow easily remove all mails?

Tags: file-management, web-services, email-client

Gmail doesnt have a clear way to do it, neither its clear with outlook at least in mobile applications. Are there email services or clients for android that would have a good enough controls allowing to do it intuitively with no Inetrnet research.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that gmail and outlook have not good enough interface, its hard to figure out hiw to delete all mails, so im looking for the other mail provider or the other client for Android.

Comment: You can connect a desktop-based email client (e.g. Mozilla Thunderbird) to your Gmail account, and manage your mailboxes with that tool. This can be a one-off task, or perhaps do this every couple of months or so.